# FieldAccessException when accessing protected field via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Why am I getting a `FieldAccessException` when trying to access a protected field with reflection in the following code?

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = foo.GetType().GetField("field", bindFlags);

        Object fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(foo);
    }
}

public class Foo 
{   
    public Foo() {
        field = 1;  
    }

    protected int field;    
}
```

This fiddle gives me the exception: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wu5vDX, but shouldn't the binding flags make sure that I am able to access the field?

Edit: Apparently, this is a .Net Fiddle only result. It only happens in the fiddle and not in Visual Studio for example.

Comment: Are you asking about the .Net Fiddle results? Protected/private fields can be read using reflection, usually.

Comment: Are you implying it might be a .Net Fiddle only result? Unfortunately, I don't have a C# environment setup to test this.

Comment: It works fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, alright then. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a restriction imposed by [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) by not running your code in [Full Trust](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831532(v%3Dws.11)) (for security reasons). Hence you're unable to leverage all the capabilities of Reflection API.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-considerations-for-reflection):

> ..., only trusted code can use reflection to access nonpublic
>   members that would not be directly accessible to compiled code.